# Spotify Web Player style UI in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, angular-ui-router

I know this is a pretty big and vague question, but if someone good give me a push in the right direction that would be great. I'm trying to build a UI in the vein of Spotify's web player (play.spotify.com), and have been struggling trying to get anything workable (using angular-ui-router and ngAnimate). The main part of the interface I'm looking to replicate is the cascading panels sliding in from the left; that is, how would I implement that using ui-views, when there are potentially infinite views transitioning in from the right, and I can't simply replace one view with another (the previous view stays on the left side of the screen). It's tough to articulate, so this may not make any sense unless you actually use their web player, but if you have had/have a play with it then you might understand.

But yeah, any conceptual overview or hints on how I would implement this with angular-ui-router (or perhaps another module I don't know about) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question will probably get downvoted because it's so vague, as you mentioned, but I'll try and help out...

Use ui-router (from the Angular UI team) instead of angular's ngRoute. You can then programmatically load in the left side view based on whatever state you want. So you'll have something like the below in your .config...

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'app/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        },
        'nav@home': {
            templateUrl: 'app/nav.html',
            controller: 'navController'
        },
        'footer@home': {
            templateUrl: 'app/footer.html'
        },
        'rightContent@home': {
            templateUrl: 'app/default.html'
        },
        'leftContent@home': {
            templateUrl: 'app/menu.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('home.leftSideOne', {
    url: 'leftSideOne',
    views: {
        'content@home.leftSideOne': {
            templateUrl: 'app/leftSideOne.html',
            controller: 'leftSideOneController'
        }
    }
})

.state('home.leftSideTwo', {
    url: 'leftSideTwo',
    views: {
        'content@home.leftSideTwo': {
            templateUrl: 'app/leftSideTwo.html',
            controller: 'leftSideTwoController'
        }
    }
})
```

Then your html could have

```
    <div ui-view="nav@home"></div>
    <div ui-view="content@{{$state.current.name}}" class="content-div"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer@home" class="footer-bar"></div>
```

And in your controller...

```
var leftLeftSide = function () {
  $state.go('home.leftSideTwo');
  // or whatever state you should be moving to
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this, a lot more detail than I was expecting.A question though, won't this replace leftSideOne with leftSideTwo when transitioning states?The part I'm struggling with that Spotify accomplish in their web player is that the previous view stays visible, but animates to the left, while the new view slides in over it. You can then click the portion of the previous view still visible to return to it.

Comment: Ah I understand. In that case you would just inject additional divs tied to the appropriate state, attach whatever styling to shrink/animate them, etc... Sounds like a really big project either way, good luck! You'll probably want to create (or maybe find?) some kind of content manager to control/add/delete all of these additional side menus